# Inserting numbering or bullets makes the text on the left of the list instead of the right

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2007, text-formatting

When I format a list ***as*** a list (numbered or bulleted)
in Microsoft Word 2007,
the text appears on the left of the list indicators (numbers or bullets). 
So instead of looking like this:

```
1. The quick brown fox
2. jumps over a lazy dog
```

It becomes like this:

```
The quick brown fox   .1
jumps over a lazy dog .2
```

**How do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure [Left-to-Right-Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBD1d.png) is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Save this macro in menu - developer - visual basic editor, 
then menu - developer - macro - Correct_RtL - run

```
Sub Correct_RtL()
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.LtrRun
    Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```

save file after it completes run.